# Powershell - How to check if file with desired creation time exists?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using this script

```
$date = Get-Date
Get-Childitem -name | where {$_.CreationTime -eq "$date"}
```

but it doesn't work. All I need is to do a boolean check if there is a file created in specific date. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Get-Date` gets the current date and time. If you compare a file's creation date with the current date **and** time you won't find any files (except you just have created one while retrieving the current date ;) ).

```
$today = (get-date).Date
Get-ChildItem | where { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $today }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem | where-object { $_.CreationTime.Date -match "2014" }
```

where `2014` is the year of creation.