# How do I find the file creation date to the bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Tell me how you can find out the date the file was created in BAT.
We have a variable for %%~ti, but it only indicates the file's modification date. And how do you know it is the date the file was created?

Comment: Doing date time handling in .bat files is quite hard. Isn't it possible for you to switch to powershell? There it is much easier, as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10433623/1838048).

Comment: There is an option:
FOR /f %%i IN ('DIR "%~1" /t:c ^| FINDSTR /E "%%~nf%%~xf"') DO ECHO %%i >> "%~2"


It is necessary to remove the recurrence

Comment: you surely mean `FINDSTR /E "%~1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ('dir /a-d /tc "%~1"') do (
  echo Date: %%a, Time: %%b, File: %~1
  exit /b 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

At least these three options exist, which are all scriptable.

There can be limitations depending on the OS version, and the language, and characters being used.

- Powershell
- WMIC
- VBS script using WSH