# Extract details from dir output in Windows XP using for loop (batch script)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, windows-7, windows-xp

I am trying to understand the `for` loop in batch scripting; in particular with `skip` and `tokens` parameters. I have found a great example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929240) followed by this nice [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44963641).

**I would like to see how I can extract the date and time from a `dir` in Windows XP** which has a slightly different `dir` output (see below example outputs) compared to Windows 7. In other words, how to extract creation date of a specific folder in Windows XP.

The following modified code from the above mentioned links correctly extracts the date and time of a `DIR` in Windows 7 but fails (i.e. extracts other characters) in Windows XP:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "path_of_folder=C:\folderA\folderB"

for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2,4 delims= " %%a in (
 'dir /ad /tc "%path_of_folder%\."') do IF "%%c"=="." (
  set "dt=%%a"
  set dirdate=%%a
  set dirtime=%%b
  echo !dirdate!, !dirtime!
  set dirday=!dirdate:~0,2!
  echo !dirday!
)
```

In **Windows 7** the `dir` command in the command prompt outputs something similar to:

```
   Directory of C:\Windows    
12/21/2016  12:56    <DIR>          . 
12/21/2016  12:56    <DIR>          .. 
09/18/2017  07.42            678    config
```

In **Windows XP** the `dir` command in the command prompt outputs something similar to:

```
   Directory of C:\WINDOWS

12/21/2016  12:56 PM    <DIR>          . 
12/21/2016  12:56 PM    <DIR>          .. 
09/18/2017  07.42 PM            678    config
```

The only difference (as far as I can notice) is the `PM` column(?) *which does not exist in Windows 7 but does exist in Windows XP*.

I know this is probably a trivial question but I am new in batch scripting and seeing a specific example using a complex `for` loop would help my understanding. *Assume use of delayed expansion*.

Comment: this depends on the time settings in the control pane. You can alter them or to use VBScript or Jscript.

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/dirTimesJS.bat)  it prints the folder times always in the same format independent from the control panel settings.

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks for the notes but I cannot alter them from VBScript or Jscript. This is for me to see a specific example (i.e. how the code will need to be modified to work under the XP's `dir` output as the shown in the question).

Comment: the link I've sent you is a jscript packed in a bat file so calling it is easy. If you need you can alter the format. Just tell me the format you need and I'll drop an example ...

Comment: @npocmaka sorry just noticed the link. it is very useful but for interest of me understanding the `for` loop through a specific example like the one above, this has no use for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time formats provided in windows listings depend on user-settings. Unfortunately, you've posted doctored listings, not actual data (evidence - exactly the same time and date for each of the data elements listed, bar the `PM` flag, despite their being allegedly on different systems)

fix : Easy way is to align the systems' UI settings - use the same format on both machines.

code to cope:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "required_format=12"

for /f "tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in (
 'type q44964366.txt^|FINDSTR /L /E /c:" ."') do (
 set "dt=%%a"
 set dirdate=%%a
 set dirtime=%%b
 IF "%%e"=="." (
  REM reading 12-hr format - convert to 24-hr
  IF "!dirtime:~0,2!"=="12" (
   IF /i "%%c"=="PM" (
    SET "dirtime=12!dirtime:~2!"
   ) else (
    SET "dirtime=00!dirtime:~2!"
   )
  ) ELSE (
   IF /i "%%c"=="PM" (
    SET /a $=2!dirtime:~0,2!-88
    SET "dirtime=!$:~-2!!dirtime:~2!"
   )
  )
 ) 
 REM else is in 24-hr format already
 IF %required_format%==12 (
  SET /a $=1!dirtime:~0,2!
  IF !$!==100 SET "dirtime=12!dirtime:~2! AM"
  IF !$! gtr 100 IF !$! leq 111 SET "dirtime=!dirtime! AM"
  IF !$!==112 SET "dirtime=12!dirtime:~2! PM"
  IF !$! gtr 112 SET /a $=$-12&SET "dirtime=!$:~-2!!dirtime:~2! PM"
 )
 echo !dirdate!, !dirtime!
 set dirday=!dirdate:~0,2!
 echo !dirday!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

For testing, I used a file containing typical `dir` lines. You would need to substitute the `dir` command from the original for the `type q44964366.txt`

The caret (`^`) before the pipe (`|`) tells `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command to be executed. The pipe outputs the data (from the `dir` command) and filds all those lines which `/L` Literally `/E` end `/c:"string"` with the constant string - note that this is <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> which neatly filters out all but the `.` directoryname, so proceeding with the analysis of the processing on the `.` name - which is the only name the `findstr` will allow through...

Since we now are using `tokens=1-5` then `%%e` can only be set to `.` if the line is in 12-hr format, else it's in 24-hr format. To convert to 24-hr format, we need to see whether `%%c` is `PM` (else it's `AM`) and if so, add 12 to the hours digits *except* for `12` in the hours digits, when we need to set the hours digits to `00` for `AM` and `12` for `PM`.

The last of these conversions is obvious, but for non-12:xx PM, we take the two hours digits and append them to `2` making a string `2hh`. `cmd` mathematics treats any numeric starting `0` as octal, so `09:xx` would create an error. `209` it can cope with as it's decimal. From that, subtract 88, which is 100-12. This produces a 3-digit number which batch treats as a string, and we need the last 2 of the characters.

You don't specify your preferred format, so we may need to conver to 12-hr (in the code, if that has been chosen in `required_format`)

In 12-hr mode, we need to subtract 12 hours if the time is PM, and take care of the special values `12:xx` and `00:xx`. This is again done by stringing the first 2 digits of the time with a constant to form a nice 3-digit decimal value. 100 means `12:xx AM` 112 means `12:xx PM` 101-111 means we simply need to add `AM` and if it's greater than 112 (eg 15:xx in 24-hour format) then we need to subtract 12 and take the last 2 characters of the result as the hours digits; then add `PM`.

And done.

---

`type q44964366.txt` replaced by the `dir` command from the original

'dir /ad /tc "%path_of_folder%."^|FINDSTR /L /E /c:" ."') do (

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I will go through it shortly. Just a note on you saying that "Unfortunately, you've posted doctored listings, not actual data (evidence - exactly the same time and date for each of the data elements listed, bar the PM flag, despite their being allegedly on different systems)": I literally copied the first 3 lines of a `dir` output on both actual Win7 and a WinXP systems. I merely modified the dates and file names to hide 'personal' and irrelevant details... :) So, the 2 outputs I provided are only modified content-wise, the columns and layout is not doctored at all.

Comment: Great answer, learning a lot. Is your approach assuming the folder is in the same level as the script? I cannot wrap my head around how to use the `path_of_folder` in your code. Is the `type` need to be replaced by the `dir` along with the `path_of_folder`?

Answer (score 1):

The different OS is not your problem, unfortunately the output of the `DIR` command is not consistent, *it can differ between users*. The simplest fix is to use an alternative method of retrieving the data you wish to capture, [npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966281/6738015) uses JScript and the following answer uses another built-in tool, `WMIC.exe`.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "_dp=C:\folderA\folderB"

Echo  Directory of %_dp% & Echo(
For %%A In ("%_dp%\*") Do (Set "_pf=%%~fA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Delims=" %%B In (`WMIC DataFile Where^
        "Drive='%%~dA' And Name='!_pf:\=\\!'" Get CreationDate^,FileSize`
    ) Do For /F "Tokens=1-2*" %%C In ("%%~B") Do (Set "_dt=%%~nxC"
        Set "_d=!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~6,2!/!_dt:~,4!"
        Set "_t=!_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2!" & Echo !_d! !_t!    %%D "%%~nxA")
        EndLocal)
Pause
```

---

**Edit**

It seems, you were looking for data from a `dir`ectory. *(I was mistaken in believing you meant the `dir` command)*.

Here is some updated code to reflect that fully:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "_dp=C:\folderA\folderB"

Echo  Directory of %_dp% & Echo(
For /D %%A In ("%_dp%\*") Do (Set "_pf=%%~fA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%B In ('
        "WMIC FSDir Where (Drive='%%~dA' And Name='!_pf:\=\\!') Get CreationDate"
    ') Do For /F %%C In ("%%~B") Do (Set "_dt=%%~nxC"
        Set "_d=!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~6,2!/!_dt:~,4!"
        Set "_t=!_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2!" & Echo !_d! !_t!    "%%~nxA")
        EndLocal)
Pause
```

---

*From memory, the very first time you run WMIC in XP there may be an initialisation delay*

The output layout can be manipulated, *as I have done…*

Comment: Thanks for you answer but when running your code I get nothing. I copied your code and modified the `_dp` path to point to my local machine. I tried adding my echoes for the `_pf` and `_dt` but they appear empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can confirm that the above code does not appear to work as it is.. Please consider modifying.

Comment: As a result of these two comments, I have tested the script on Windows Vista, 7 and 10 and found them all to work as expected. The common denominator between all three were the OS language localisation settings. The first possiblity I can think of is that the WMIC output header is language dependent. I have now changed the code to cater for that possibility, please recheck and feedback as necessary; thank you.

Comment: You are using DATAFILE, which reports on files. But the OP (@nk-fford) is trying to get info about a folder, which is why your code returns nothing. You need to use FSDIR instead.

Comment: You can use `wmic fsdir where "name='%_dp:\=\\%'" get ...`

Comment: Thanks @dbenham. [nk-fford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167676/nk-fford), I have updated my answer accordingly to correct my misunderstanding, see **Edit** section.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` command time format is dependent on the settings in the control panel.
To get the directory creation time independent from the control panel settings you can use [dirtimejs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/dirTimesJS.bat):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "path_of_folder=C:\folderA\folderB"

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('dirtimejs.bat "%path_of_folder%" ^| find "Created :"') do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims=:- " %%A in ("%%b") do (
        echo dir year: %%A
        echo dir month : %%B
        echo dir day :  %%C 
    )
)
```

To see what information `dirtimejs` try with `dirtimejs.bat "%path_of_folder%"`.

Comment: very useful indeed, but I would prefer an example that works on the XP dir output (modification of the code I provided which works on Windows 7) by not using any 3rd party code like the ditimejs.bat

Comment: @nk-fford - this will work on XP - jscript is part of widows script host which is installed on every windows machine by default since Windows NT. As the `dirtimejs.bat` is not a binary you can copy it, change it and use it as you find comfortable.

Comment: I understand and indeed provides a fix. However, the essence of my question was to see an example code implementation to aid my understanding. That is why I hope someone will provide that. I appreciate your response either way.